# Best openGL tool(s) to utilize to randomly access 1GB of data from within a shader?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, gpu

I have a data structure that will be huge, around 1gb. I need to be able to randomly access this from within shader.

It's possible for me to split up the structure into smaller containers, but then I would have to bind everything and do multiple draw calls and this would decrease performance.

I would like to target the oldest version of opengl as possible, but i'd rather use a higher version than have a hacky or unelegant solution.

Buffer textures are to small. Even SSBO's are too small. Any ideas?

The only other thing I can think of is PRTs but I have no experience with these and I don't know if it's suited for my needs.

Comment: Why are buffer textures "too small"? They're as big as the buffer you can create to back them, but I guess you can't just create a 1GB buffer (i.e. fragmentation on the GPU will cause such an allocation to fail)?

Comment: @peppe I have a pretty high end machine and the max I can allocate with a buffer texture is only 230 megs, i checked using the opengl get command

Comment: I do not know what you want to do with this huge dataset, but if you want to do some calculations or even rendering an image I suggest taking a look at CUDA / OpenCL. You can upload textures, and use textures as output if you want. As far as i know there is no limitation (only physical) on memory. 
As shading is only math you can implement everything using cuda.

Comment: Well, you probably could use ordinary _textures_  (or maybe array textures) instead of TBOs. If you go for the really modern stuff, there will be _sparse textures_ and _bindless textures_, which might also be of some use here.

Comment: @derhass how could I use ordinary textures? Does sparse textures work if you fill the entire texture up anyway? Bindless textures is the most recent of recent features so i'd rather avoid it if possible. I have no experience with OpenCL and i'd rather not learn it just for this one thing

Comment: @BlazArt: Well, let's forget sparse textures and bindless textures. With ordinary textures you can use samplers and `texelFetch()` for read-only access and [GL_ARB_image_load_store](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt) (which went into core in GL 4.2) will allow you to use [`imageLoad()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/imageLoad.xml) and [`imageStore()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/imageStore.xml) for read-write access.

Comment: @BlazArt: it is just the question what kind of texture you would use, a 1D texure is probably too limited. Texture 2D is typically limited to 16384x16384 on current hardware, with 4 channels and one byte/channel that will be exactly 1GB, but you may want to use some other layout. Array textures would help here, too, you just will need some 3-dimensional organization of your data, but that is easy to map to a linear buffer and vice-versa.